# How to open a new terminal window and do things there from a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to fully automate my simulation scripting under Linux. Currently, I manually click open a terminal, enter the commands to get the simulation running, click open another terminal, and do the similar things.

What I have done so far is having multiple shell scripts, each of which opens one terminal and does the stuff. Despite having little experience with shell script, I believe this can be automated with one single shell script.

How may I open multiple terminal windows and do different stuff in those terminals from **one single** shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute your commands/scripts in sequence, just write them in a file, each per line, then `bash theFile`

if you want to start/run a number of job in parallel, you may want to check this out:  http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

If you want to start/run commands in different terminal but you don't want to manually "click". tmux/screen would be your friend. with tmux, you can define when it starts, open how many windows/panes, and in each window/pane which command should be fired.

tmux link: http://tmux.sourceforge.net

P.S. tmux is very handy tool, I work everyday with it. It is must-have tool 4 me.

Comment: +1 for tmux, it allows the solution to work on headless boxes as well